# How do i get visual studio 2008 to create a class for my MFC dialog resource?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, dialog, wizard

I used to use VC 6 a while back and there was a simple to use "wizard" that would create a class out of a dialog created in the GUI editor.

I am using 2008 professional and there seems to be no way to generate this.  I can try to make it based on a template of previous projects, but it seems to me that is missing.

Where did they bury that functionality?

Comment: So right-clicking on the class, and selecting 'View Code' isn't what you are looking for? What type of class are you looking for?

Comment: You may want to either accept some answers to your previous questions or give feedback as to why none of the answers are suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6761383e.aspx). :)

Comment: Thanks.  that's typical - they bury the functionality and the other places where i got that dialog box i was unable to specify a dialog resource even after choosing CDialog as the base.  Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

I double-click on the dialog and am prompted to create a new class.